# Angular Kinematics and conservation of Energy: A uniform, thin rod of length L and mass M pivots vertically

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, angular-velocity

[image: The Rod pivots from point A to point B]

In the above image a rod is released at Point A and travels to point B. The question in this case is to find an expression for the velocity at point B.
I attempted this in two ways, conservation of energy and angular kinematics.

With the conservation of energy, you can find that $mgh=1/2I\omega^2$.

substituting $L/2$ for the height and $(ML^2)/3$ for $I$ you find $MgL/2 = 1/6[ML^2(V^2/L^2)]$

That simplifies to $ v =\sqrt{3gL}$

---

When you use angular kinematics, however, you can find that the torque is equal to $MgL/2$ because the average point away from the axis of rotation is halfway through the rod.

Using the equation $\alpha = \tau_{net}/I$ you can find that $\alpha = [(L/2)Mg/(ML^2)/3]$, simplified to $3g/2L$
you can then use the equation $\omega_f^2 = \omega_i^2+2\alpha\theta$ to find that $\omega_f^2 = 0 + 2(3g/2L)\pi/2$, which simplifies to $\omega=\sqrt{(3/2)\pi*g/L}$ multiplying both sides by L will give you $v = \sqrt{(3/2)\pi*gL}$

apparently the conservation of energy answer is right

**My Question:** why is the conservation of energy answer right, and what causes the disparity between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I solve this hinged-rod problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404198)

Comment: For angular kinematics , try using work done $W=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tau .d\theta$ ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The torque is a function of position (you have it fixed at the $\theta=\pi/2$ value-so your velocity from that method should be too high):

$$I \ddot \theta = \frac 1 3ML^2\ddot\theta  =\tau(\theta) = -\frac 1 2 MgL \sin{\theta} $$
so

$$\ddot\theta =-\frac{3g}{2L}\sin{\theta} $$

or
$$\ddot\theta+\frac{3g}{2L}\sin{\theta}=0 $$

So, solve that and find $L\dot\theta_{\theta=0}$.